# How can we get rid of slimes on super flat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I live in a village and these slimes are ruining my game, please help me get rid of them!

Comment: that...seem to be very large number of them to be naturally generated

Comment: i did say like amd theres 4 viliges         #scince

Comment: @minecraftrules btw. [Minecraft Gamepedia](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Spawn) says "cap = constant * chunks / 256" with slimes constant being 70. Biggest village I've ever seen was 5x5 chunks, so the cap is 70 * 25 / 256, which makes 6,8 slimes max for a village. So, 24 is the number of maximum slimes in your 4 villages. #Math ps. The number 6,8 and 24 still counts other animals (like Zombie, Creeper, Pig, Cow etc.) and not just slimes!

Answer (score 16):

`/kill @e[type=Slime]` will kill all the Slimes in the world while leaving everything else alone. With this command in a [Command Block](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/236324/how-can-i-get-a-command-block), an automatic elimination of Slimes is possible: Just set it to Repeat and Always Active, and then you're done.

Comment: 1.13 (actually earlier) syntax: `/kill @e[type=slime]`

Comment: I would suggest setting `/gamerule doMobLoot` to `False` before doing this and reverting it to `True` when done. This avoids loot drop lag.

Answer (score 7):

You can change your difficulty to peaceful.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a redstone loop + command block system to constantly remove any unwanted entities(Mobs, Items, Item frames, etc.)

First, create your RS loop (shown below)

`Top-down view
[r][#][B] 
[r][r][t]`

Key: 
`[r]` = Redstone wire (dust) 
`[B]` = Any *solid* block, wool works fine 
`[t]` = Redstone torch 
`[#]` = A redstone repeater set to 3 ticks

Now connect any number of Command Blocks (to get Command Blocks enter `/give _USERNAME_ minecraft:command_block 1` into the chat) equal to the amount of entities you want to be *cleaned up* to the redstone wire on that loop.

Enter the following command into the Command Block(s) connected to your loop, replacing `_ENTITY_` with the name of the entity you want removed (ei. Cow, Bat, Pig, Spider, Skeleton, Slime):

`/kill @e[type=_ENTITY_]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of them permanently, run this command (this will prevent all other types of mobs from spawning):

```
/gamerule doMobSpawning false
```

And then this:

```
/tp @e[type=Slime] ~ -300 ~
```

Comment: isn't better /gamerule doslimeSpawning false ? :D

Comment: The only answer on the internet to actually accomplish what I've been looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

`/kill @e[type=Slime]` is how you kill them, but put it on a repeater to help.

Comment: This adds nothing beyond what was already said in existing answers.