# How can I get a command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know how to enable cheats, but when I search *command block* in my creative inventory, I can't find it. Where do I get it?

Answer (score 5):

Press <kbd>T</kbd> and then <kbd>/</kbd>, or just <kbd>/</kbd> to bring up the command, then type `/give @p command_block` and press the *enter key* (<kbd>↵</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Answer (score 2):

You will first need to type `/` to start typing commands, then, after that, type:

```
/give @p minecraft:command_block
```

Just for notation, a `command block`'s ID is <kbd>137</kbd>

Comment: It's generally better to suggest an edit to an existing answer if your answer isn't going to be significantly different.

Answer (score 2):

mc version 1.10:

```
/give (userid) minecraft:command_block
```

mc version 1.9 and under:

```
/give (userid) command_block
```

Answer (score 1):

To get command blocks in Minecraft, you type /give (Your username) command_block.

Answer (score 1):

type this command: **/give @p command_block**